# python functions returning functions

Tags: python, function, functional-programming

I am aware of the `partial` function in `functools`, but how common is it in general python programs (not: Haskell, Erlang, Clojure etc ) to write functions to return functions in Python?

for example:

```
>>> def returnfunk(xs):
...     return lambda x: list(filter(lambda y: x == y, xs))
... 
>>> fn = returnfunk(["cat", "dog", "horse"])
>>> 
>>> (fn("cow") == []) == True
True
>>> (fn("cat") == ['cat']) == True
True
>>> 
>>> list(filter(fn, ["zebra", "elephant", "dog", "parrot", "cat"]))
['dog', 'cat']
```

is it meant for the `real (python) world` or more for hobby, academic, interest?

Comment: It's highly common, functions are just another kind of object. The function you've written to return is obtuse though, you'd use a list comprehension.

Comment: This isn't really an answerable question... How is "common" defined? An answers definition might differ from your own.

Comment: I suppose I meant - is it an approach that the Python community generally supports? I appreciate that things can be done in a functional style, but I did not know for example about pluggable interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decorators `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` are two examples.

Comment: Every decorator is an example.

Answer (score 1):

It's very much used in the real world.  The first thing that comes to my mind are APIs with pluggable interfaces.  Most operate by implementing a function registry then doing lookups in to that registry.

Answer (score 1):

They are very useful. Functional programming uses this kind of thing all the time and it can greatly simplify tasks such as `filter` in the way you used above (though there are much easier ways to accomplish what you were trying to do there).

Answer (score 1):

It is meant for flexibility. There are a wide variety of things you can do with functions returning functions, like currying, combination and decoration. And of course it allows you to toy with closures, which gives you great flexibility in coding. Whether you need it or not strongly depends on your application.