# Why variables in python do use function like syntax with () in front of the variables name but they are actually not function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

1. How many ways a variable could be defined in python?
2. Is there any way a variable can call a another variable through function like notation?

For Example:

```
 from tensorflow.keras import layers

 inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,))


 dense = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')

 x = dense(inputs)
```

My Question is *dense* is a variable it is taking *inputs* as an argument like functions does.

[The Keras functional API in TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional)

Comment: Dense is a function not a variable. You must tell it how many fully connected nodes to have in that layer - it’s argument.

Comment: `dense` is a variable, and that variable holds a reference to a function.

Comment: Your question isn't clearly asking one specific thing (the title has a question in it, the first two sentences are different questions, and the last line is another question), but this other post may clear up your confusion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728511/python-functions-returning-functions

Comment: What about "x = dense(inputs)" this line with small letter dense variable which taking inputs within () bracket.Dense is a class in the tf.keras.layers.Dense https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense

Comment: @kaya3 both inputs & dense are variable.

Comment: Oh you were referring to the variable you named “dense”. The reason you can use brackets there is because of Keras functional API. Essentially your last line says feed the input to the layer which you defined with the variable “dense”. See more here: https://keras.io/models/model/

Answer (score 0):

A variable may have different types such as `int` and `function` in runtime, which can be inspected with the `type()` built-in function.

Also variable can be used with `()` like a function when its reference is  `callable`, which can be tested using the `callable()` built-in function.

Furthermore, in Python a function can return another function and a class instance can be made callable, like a function.

Here is an example to illustrate, first we define 3 simple functions:

```
def sum(a, b):
    return a + b

def mul(a, b):
    return a * b

def noop(a, b):
    pass
```

Then we define a function that takes one argument and returns another function:

```
def chooseOperation(sign):
    operations = {"+": sum, "*": mul} # sum and mul are functions
    return operations[sign] if sign in operations else noop # noop is a function
```

Finally, we declare a variable that receives the result of a function call, which is a reference to one of those simple functions.

```
operation = chooseOperation("+") # returns sum
print(operation(2, 3)) # 5

operation = chooseOperation("*") # returns mul
print(operation(2, 3)) # 6

operation = chooseOperation("%") # returns noop
print(operation(2, 3)) # None
```

You can inspect a variable type with `type(variable)`:

```
print(type(operation)) # <class 'function'>
```

Therefore, if a variable is of type `<class 'function'>` it means you can call that function through this variable.

In the case of `Dense` from TensorFlow API, its type is as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers

dense = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')

print(type(dense)) # <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense'>
print(callable(dense)) # True
```

The important part to understand is that the `dense` variable references an instance of the class `Dense`, which is `callable`. This is what allows you to use `()` with the `dense` variable.

The TensorFlow API [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python) may be a little too much to ingest, so consider this simple example:

```
class Dense():

    def sum(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def __call__(self, a, b): # Instances will now be callable
        return self.sum(a, b)

dense = Dense() # Dense constructor, no args

print(type(dense)) # <class '__main__.Dense'>

sum = dense(1, 6) # 7 - Triggers __call__ which in turn calls sum(1, 6)
```

When a class implements `__call__` its instances become `callable`, like a function.

The way it is implemented in TensorFlow API is a bit different due to the more complex inheritance structure but follows the same principle.